NX Required property 'browserTarget' is missing eventhough it's deprecated
When I run my angular app, I get the warning
Option "browserTarget" is deprecated: Use 'buildTarget' instead
I had several references of "browserTarget" in the file .../project.json and changed it to buildTarget accordingly.
npm run start still works and the warning is gone.
However, when I run nx app-shell --configuration=production I now get the error:
NX   Required property 'browserTarget' is missing
I made sure that no more references to browserTarget exist in my app. I suspect that the error might have to do with version-incompatibility.
The result of nx --version:

Local: v18.2.4
Global: v19.5.2

The result of ng version:
Angular CLI: 17.3.8
Node: 20.15.0
Package Manager: npm 10.8.2

Angular: 17.3.3

@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.3
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.3
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.3
@angular/cli                    17.3.8
@schematics/angular             17.3.3
ng-packagr                      17.3.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.4
zone.js                         0.14.4

Can this be fixed? Or should I rather change all references back to browserTarget and just ignore the deprecation warning?

Make sure that the setup in project.json file is correct.
The browserTarget option has been deprecated in ng17 cli. Instead, you should use the buildTarget option.
Here is an example of how buildTarget is used :
...

"serve": {
  "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "test:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "buildTarget": "test:build:development"
    },
    "staging": {
      "buildTarget": "test:build:staging"
    },
    "local": {
      "buildTarget": "test:build:local"
    }
  },
  "defaultConfiguration": "local"
},
...

Run : nx run test:serve --configuration=production
